# Excel VBA How to convert sections of string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a File that has orders history that was downloaded from an old e-commerce website I am trying to convert the data to be uploaded onto a new site. It is a csv file so I am working in excel. There are 20 columns of data one of the columns has the Items Ordered (original text string) each row has data from one order. I need to do convert the data from the the original text string so it ends up with only the required fields in the order and format as shown in the converted text string example below.

original text string

```
Product ID: 1234, Product Qty: 2, Product SKU: Brush, Product Name: Brush, Product Weight: 80.0000, Product Variation Details: , Product Unit Price: 5.00, Product Total Price: 10.00|Product ID: 2345, Product Qty: 5, Product SKU: Comb, Product Name: Comb, Product Weight: 1.3000, Product Variation Details: , Product Unit Price: 1.00, Product Total Price: 5.00
```

converted text string

product_id:1234|quantity:2|subtotal:5.00|total:10.00|;product_id:2345|quantity:5|subtotal:1.00|total:5.00

Comment: Is your original text string a single "paragraph" like you have it or multiple rows, with a row for each Product ID?

Comment: it is a text string not a paragraph

Answer (score 1):

below is not a complete solution for you (because currently it is hard to understand from OP what is real outcome should be), but an example which you can adopt to cover your requirements:

```
Sub test()
    Dim S1$, k1, k2
    S1 = "Product ID: 35, Product Qty: 2, Product SKU: Brush, Product Name: Brush, Product Weight: 80.0000, Product Variation Details: , Product Unit Price: 5.00, Product Total Price: 10.00|Product ID: 54, Product Qty: 5, Product SKU: Comb, Product Name: Comb, Product Weight: 1.3000, Product Variation Details: , Product Unit Price: 1.00, Product Total Price: 5.00"
    For Each k1 In Split(S1, "|")
        For Each k2 In Split(k1, ",")
            If UCase(k2) Like "*ID*" Or _
                UCase(k2) Like "*QTY*" Or _
                    UCase(k2) Like "*PRICE*" Then
                Debug.Print k2
            End If
    Next k2, k1
End Sub
```

test:

[image]